# 3D model not loading correctly in Scenekit

Tags: ios, scenekit, blender, arkit, collada

So I purchased a 3D model of a car to display in my ARKIT app.The folder consisted of different model formats and a single image.

I dragged and dropped the .dae file to my project. This is the file structure.

[image]

However when adding to the scene the axis would be completely off and not load correctly. It did not load the complete model with textures, and would load above me.

**See example:**

[image]

Then I decided to load the .Blender file in Blender and export again as a colada .dae file.

[image]

This was the result when adding to my project.

[image]

[image]

When loading it in the real world a half car would appear where I stood at a ridiculously large scale.

I have tried the project with a separate model and it worked fine. Does anyone have any ideas how I can work with the 3D Model to load correctly in my app ?

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems scaling models I have purchased.  You aren't supposed to post links, but it's too big to paste in - I followed this guide to scale down the models and rotate them into the proper position in blender before exporting.

https://jibransyed.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/how-to-correct-scale-and-rotation-of-static-blender-models-for-unity/

On most models I use this to load:

```
func loadCollada(sceneName: String, objName: String) -> SCNNode
    {
        let vScene = SCNScene(named: sceneName)!
        let gObject = vScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: objName, 
 recursively: true)!
        return gObject
      }
```

On some larger models, I had to do it this way:

```
func collada2SCNNode(filepath: String) -> SCNNode
{
    let returnNode = SCNNode()
    let scene = SCNScene(named: filepath)
    for vNode in (scene?.rootNode.childNodes)!
    {
        returnNode.addChildNode(vNode)
    }
    return returnNode
}
```

Then set Y UP: 
scntool --convert fighter0.dae --format c3d --output out.dae --force-y-up --force-interleaved --look-for-pvrtc-image